# Add Some new words and the audio to Kotlin's text to speech Library

Tags: android, kotlin, text-to-speech

I am currently working on a project using kotlin's text to speech. is there a way we can do to add some new words and its audio to the library? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin doesn't have a text to speech library.  Android has a text to speech framework, so I assume you mean that.  Look into TextToSpeech.addEarcon and TextToSpeech.addSpeech.  One of those may be what you're looking for.

Comment: okay ill try first, Thank you for answering

Comment: Do you have the documentation like how to use it?